# typo3 8.7.9 - download language package and update extension list failed

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

I already installed TYPO3 8.7.9, changed the language to german but can't download the language pack. It says:

**Error
The request has failed.**

Also if I change the dropdown in Extensions to Get Extensions it says:

**Update Extension List
Could not access remote resource https://repositories.typo3.org/mirrors.xml.gz**

I'm using MAMP on Windows 7. Also in the System environment check there are four orange issues which - I thought - already fixed in the php.ini:

- Low PHP script execution time
- PHP max_input_vars very low
- Windows apache thread stack size
- PHP extension fileinfo not loaded

Do you think it had something to do with "curl"? It often appears during my Google research.

I would be pleased if someone could help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I can access this file via browser, so it's available. A missing `curl` could be the problem, you're right.

Comment: Problem solved! I was editing the wrong php.ini-files in MAMP\bin\php\php7.1.5\. The php.ini in conf should contain this line with semikolon: ;extension=php_curl.dll